# How is this strict aliasing undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, union, strict-aliasing

I know, I saw it already but I couldn't find any good explanation why is this undefined behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//Common union for both types
union float_int {
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
};

int main(void) {
    union float_int fi;
    //This should be problematic
    uint32_t* i_ptr = (uint32_t *)&fi.f;

    fi.f = 10.0f;
    printf("%f : %u\r\n", fi.f, fi.i); //Prints: 10.000000 : 1092616192 which is OK
    printf("%u\r\n", *i_ptr); //Prints: 1092616192 which is also OK

    return 0;
}
```

If we check memory representation, both are `4-bytes` long so there is no *memory overflow* in pointing or similar.

How is this undefined behaviour?

```
int main() {
    union float_int fi;
    void* v_ptr = &fi.f;
    uint32_t* i_ptr = (uint32_t *)v_ptr;
}
```

Is this code still undefined behaviour? I want to read `float` number as `unsigned integer 32-bits`.

Why is using `memcpy` the only available way of doing it?

Comment: `indefined` --> `undefined`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, Thanks.

Comment: @Stargateur give me correct answer, please. I couldn't find it.

Comment: While type-punning through unions is explicitly allowed by the C specification (unlike C++), I'm not so sure about you using pointers to the "wrong" members. If you, in your first example, using e.g. `uint32_t* i_ptr = &fi.i` then that would be okay, even if `&fi.f` is the same address and memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc, strict-aliasing, and casting through a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906365/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-casting-through-a-union) or/and [Is the strict aliasing rule incorrectly specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798140/is-the-strict-aliasing-rule-incorrectly-specified)

Comment: @tilz0R try the following: `void testalias(union float_int *fi, uint32_t *i_ptr)
{
    *i_ptr = 42;
    fi->f = 10.0f;

    printf("%f\n", fi->f);
    printf("%d\n", *i_ptr);
}
int main(void) {
    union float_int fi;
    uint32_t* i_ptr = (uint32_t *)&fi.f;

    testalias(&fi, i_ptr);

    return 0;
}` This will print `10.000000` and some corresponding `int` as you expect (note that reading this `int` from the union is already undefined, it wasn't the last object stored) [cont'd]

Comment: @tilz0R then move the `testalias` function to a separate translation unit. At least with my gcc version and `-O3`, the result is that it prints `0.000000 42`. The compiler assumes the two pointers not to alias each other as they have incompatible types, so it can reorder the assignments "safely" (of course, it can't, due to the forbidden aliasing).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, this will print 10.000.. as float because float was last assigned to the union. Ok, so here is optimization.

Comment: @tilz0R sure this is about optimization, *without* the strict aliasing rule, many optimizations wouldn't be possible. Just don't alias incompatible pointers (and don't read from a `union` member other than the member last written to, except when they are both structs with a common initial sequence)

Comment: @FelixPalmen if you check this code: `struct buff {int a; int b; int c;}; char tmp[sizeof(struct buff)]; struct buff b; b.a = 5; memcpy(tmp, &buff, sizeof(buff)); struct buff* ptr = (struct buff *)tmp; printf("%d\r\n", ptr->a);` Is it valid for you? For me it is and I can see this approach on many libraries (LwIP is one of them). Let's assume we have 2 same devices (MCU) and they communicate between with UART and they send structure as bytes. Is this undefined?

Comment: @tilz0R if you ever really **need** to access the representation of some object, use a `char *` for it -- this is the only thing allowed in C.

Comment: @tilz0R no, invalid as well, `tmp` is of type `char` and you're aliasing it with some struct pointer. Only the other way around is valid (aliasing anything *using* a `char` pointer).

Comment: If `tmp` would be `void *` then everything would be ok, I assume?
*void* tmp2 = tmp; memcpy(tmp2, &buff, sizeof(buff));` and then `struct buff* ptr = tmp2`? If this is still not valid, how can then all these libraries work by using this approach?

Comment: @tilz0R regarding your edit, yes, this **is** undefined. It can still work if you **know** that your `char` buffer contains a valid representation and you won't have problems as long as you don't mix accesses through your `char` pointer and the casted one. But this way, you create code outside of the spec that will only work on your target platform.

Comment: Can we continue on chat @FelixPalmen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148471/discussion-between-felix-palmen-and-tilz0r).

Comment: The [tag:union] tag is only for the SQL "union" keyword @tilzOR; the correct tag for c-style unions is [tag:unions]. For reference please see linked tag wikis.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strict aliasing, it is a *violation* of strict aliasing.

First, you are doing

```
 uint32_t* i_ptr = (uint32_t *)&fi.f;   //converting to a non-character type pointer
```

and then, you try to access that by

```
  printf("%u\r\n", *i_ptr);   //access value via incompatible lvalue expr.
```

which causes the issue. `float` and `uint32_t` are **not** compatible types.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5/P7

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types: <sup>88)</sup>
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

---

In reply to the comment, let's see `C11`, chapter §6.2.6.1

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of `n × CHAR_BIT`
>   bits, where `n` is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into
>   an object of type `unsigned char [n]` (e.g., by `memcpy`); the resulting set of bytes is
>   called the object representation of the value.

and

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
>   value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
>   not have character type, the behavior is undefined. [...] Such a representation is called
>   a trap representation.

Comment: I agree that they are not, but both are 4-bytes long and both point to the same memory. CPU don't care what is there, it is just how you read and interpret it. Strange though for me. And only `memcpy` could resolve this. Even more strange. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @tilz0R OK, let me expand.

Comment: Hope I find a casting of buffer in one answer. Similar situation. Thanks for update.

Comment: `struct buff {int a; int b; int c;}; char tmp[sizeof(struct buff)]; struct buff b; b.a = 5; memcpy(tmp, &buff, sizeof(buff)); struct buff* ptr = (struct buff *)tmp; printf("%d\r\n", ptr->a);` Is this valid code? Let's assume values from `tmp` were received by UART from the same device (both identical devices communicating from UART, one is sending structure, second receiving the same one).

Comment: @tilz0R looks invalid, what is `&buff`? you meant `&b`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `&b`.

Comment: @tilz0R even in that case, I believe, `char *` (or, generics, pointer to character types) aliases all, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Float and integer representations are different from one another.
This is why by defining such a union, is not a good use case.

In your example, you perform casting from void* to uint32_t*.
The casting is done in pointer-level. 
It means that i_ptr points to a location in memory, viewed as an interger, without changing the bits themselves.

To summarize, if you want this casting to work, you'll need to modify the internal representation of the variable. For example:

```
printf("%u\r\n", (uint32_t)*i_ptr);
```

Comment: "defining a union, such that ... is not possible": this doesn't make sense. It would meand that no union is possible at all !

Comment: @YvesDaoust agree, I rephrased it to be more accurate